# Multiple MATCH-AGAINST clauses results in no FULLTEXT index being used

Tags: sql, mariadb, full-text-search, explain

I have the following two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `lname` (
  `lnameid` binary(16) NOT NULL,
  `lid` binary(16) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `namerank` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `score` float DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`lnameid`),
  KEY `lid` (`lid`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `name` (`name`),
  CONSTRAINT `lname_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`lid`) REFERENCES `sl` (`lid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE `sl` (
  `lid` binary(16) NOT NULL,
  `sid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `laid` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `definition` text DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`lid`),
  KEY `sid` (`sid`),
  KEY `laid` (`laid`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `definition` (`definition`),
  CONSTRAINT `sl_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`sid`) REFERENCES `s` (`sid`),
  CONSTRAINT `sl_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`laid`) REFERENCES `la` (`laid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci
```

And the following query:

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT MATCH(lname.name) AGAINST ('maillot' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS nms,
       MATCH(sl.definition) AGAINST ('maillot' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS dms
FROM   sl
INNER JOIN lname ON lname.lid = sl.lid
WHERE  MATCH(sl.definition) AGAINST ('maillot' IN BOOLEAN MODE) > 0
OR     MATCH(lname.name) AGAINST ('maillot' IN BOOLEAN MODE) > 0;
+------+-------------+-----------------+------+---------------+---------------+---------+----------------------------------+--------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table           | type | possible_keys | key           | key_len | ref                              | rows   | Extra       |
+------+-------------+-----------------+------+---------------+---------------+---------+----------------------------------+--------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | sl              | ALL  | PRIMARY       | NULL          | NULL    | NULL                             | 130437 |             |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | lname           | ref  | lid           | lid           | 16      | lid                              | 1      | Using where |
+------+-------------+-----------------+------+---------------+---------------+---------+----------------------------------+--------+-------------+
```

As you can see, none of the two `FULLTEXT` indexes are being used.

If I only apply one `MATCH` (either the first or the second one, and keeping the `JOIN` clause as-is), the corresponding `FULLTEXT` index is used.

I don't understand why multiple `MATCH` clauses suddenly cause MariaDB to stop using the indexes

I am using MariaDB 10.5.19.

Comment: your create table sl fails, there's no slid column.  was sid supposed to be slid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OR forces the query ti make a full table scan so a use of the indexdes makes no sense.

changing it to

```
CREATE TABLE `sl` (
  `slid` binary(16) NOT NULL,
  `sid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `laid` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `definition` text DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`slid`),
  KEY `sid` (`sid`),
  KEY `laid` (`laid`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `definition` (`definition`)#,
  #CONSTRAINT `sl_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`sid`) REFERENCES `s` (`sid`),
  #CONSTRAINT `sl_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`laid`) REFERENCES `la` (`laid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci
```

```
CREATE TABLE `lname` (
  `lnameid` binary(16) NOT NULL,
  `lid` binary(16) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `namerank` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `score` float DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`lnameid`),
  KEY `lid` (`lid`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `name` (`name`),
  CONSTRAINT `lname_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`lid`) REFERENCES `sl` (`slid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci
```

```
EXPLAIN 
  SELECT MATCH(lname.name) AGAINST ('maillot' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS nms,
       MATCH(sl.definition) AGAINST ('maillot' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS dms
FROM   sl
INNER JOIN lname ON lname.lid = sl.slid
WHERE  MATCH(sl.definition) AGAINST ('maillot' IN BOOLEAN MODE) > 0
  UNION
  SELECT MATCH(lname.name) AGAINST ('maillot' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS nms,
       MATCH(sl.definition) AGAINST ('maillot' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS dms
FROM   sl
INNER JOIN lname ON lname.lid = sl.slid
  WHERE MATCH(lname.name) AGAINST ('maillot' IN BOOLEAN MODE) > 0;
```

| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PRIMARY | sl | fulltext | PRIMARY,definition | definition | 0 |  | 1 | Using where |
| 1 | PRIMARY | lname | ALL | lid | *null* | *null* | *null* | 1 | Using where |
| 2 | UNION | sl | ALL | PRIMARY | *null* | *null* | *null* | 1 |  |
| 2 | UNION | lname | fulltext | lid,name | name | 0 |  | 1 | Using where |
| *null* | UNION RESULT | <union1,2> | ALL | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* |  |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/MTWtYAzO)

Comment: The UNION was a possible workaround, I understand, but why does OR cause a full table scan? Would you mind pointing me to a resource explaining why this happens? So that I can learn and avoid asking questions (I'm done for the week I think though:)

Comment: that is quite simple your indexes point to both tables, but mariadb, only can use 1 of them, so it can't determine which rows should be included by using any index, the union split and so it can use both indexes

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Why cannot MariaDB use only one index? Is it a limitation of innodb, or do you mean that using multiple index is not doable, it does not make sense? (I mean, the 'OR' implementation could perform a UNION internally, couldn't it?)

Comment: all databases systems only can use 1 indexe, i don't know why, you can ask the myriadb developers, but basically they write a compiler, which can not use all avenues, so it takes short cut called heuristics, to find a good way through the code. i imagine, that it can be complex to add another rindex with the hole logic, also it would take more time, which you can spend elsewhere, but that is what  i learned in university, there maybe more, you can ask the developers